While saving Datapane report using pandas library, I'm getting an attribute error saying that pandas has no attribute 'Int64Index
I'm having issues saving my datapane report because I keep getting this error message: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Index'." What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? Can anyone explain what this error signifies and suggest possible solutions? Also, any tips on using datapane libraries more effectively would be appreciated.
error line --> dp.save_report(v, path=f"{client}_TelemetryReport_{end_date_str}.html", open=True)
While trying to save the datapane report file (HTML), I'm getting this error. I'm currently using the pandas version 2.0.3 . I didn't use aany set index or any index driven opereations in the code on any dataframes.
error line --> dp.save_report(v, path=f"{client}_TelemetryReport_{end_date_str}.html", open=True)
complete error -->
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-8d088ae7c97e> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 )
     17 
---> 18 dp.save_report(v, path=f"{client}_TelemetryReport_{end_date_str}.html", open=True)

36 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datapane/common/df_processor.py in convert_axis(df)
     24     if isinstance(df.index, pd.RangeIndex):
     25         pass  # allow RangeIndex - reset numbers?
---> 26     elif isinstance(df.index, pd.Int64Index):
     27         df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
     28     else:

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Index'

Tried all the stack overflow suggested solutions but still the same error persisited. Then tried to upgrade the pandas version and decreased it too but of no use.

Google for "pandas Int64Index" and find: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html

The code uses things that are deprecated in new Pandas versions (see the linked duplicate) - therefore, it is not compatible with the version of Pandas you have installed. You will need to upgrade the library (if possible), downgrade Pandas or file a bug report.
